# Keras Bidirectional LSTM - Layer grouping

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

While working to implement a paper (*Dialogue Act Sequence Labeling using Hierarchical encoder with CRF*) using Keras, I need to implement a specific Bidirectional LSTM architecture.

I have to train the network on the concept of a Conversation. Conversations are composed of Utterances, and Utterances are composed of Words. Words are N-dimensional vectors. The model represented in the paper first reduces each Utterance to a single `M`-dimensional vector. To achieve this, it uses a Bidirectional LSTM layer. Let's call this layer **A**.

(For simplicity, let's assume that each Utterance has a length of `|U|` and each Conversation has a length of `|C|`)

Each Utterance is input to a Bi-LSTM layer with U timesteps, and the output of the last timestep is taken. The input size is `(|U|, N)`, and the output size is `(1, M)`.

This Bi-LSTM layer should be applied separately/simultaneously to each Utterance in the Conversation. Note that, since the network takes as input the entire Conversation, the dimensions for a single input to the network would be `(|C|, |U|, N)`.

As the paper describes, I intend to feed each utterance (i.e. each `(|U|, N)`) of that input and feed it to a Bi-LSTM layer with `|U|` units. As there are |C| Utterances in a Conversation, this implies that there should be a total of `|C| x |U|` Bi-LSTM units, grouped into `|C|` different partitions for each Utterance. There should be no connection between the `|C|` groups of units. Once processed, the output of each of those `C` groups of Bidirectional LSTM units will then be fed into another Bi-LSTM layer, say **B**.

How is it possible to feed specific portions of the input only to specific portions of the layer **A**, and make sure that they are not interconnected? (i.e. the portion of Bi-LSTM units used for an Utterance should not be connected to the Bi-LSTM units used for another Utterance)

Is it possible to achieve this through `keras.models.Sequential`, or is there a specific way to achieve this using Functional API?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
# ...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(C * U), input_shape = (C, U, N),
                        merge_mode='concat'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(n, return_sequences = True), merge_mode='concat'))
# ...

model.compile(loss = loss_function,
              optimizer = optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, this code is currently receiving the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

More importantly, the code above obviously does not do the grouping I mentioned. I am looking for a way to enhance the model as I described above.

Finally, below is the figure of the model I described above. It may possibly help clarify some of the written content narrated above. The layer tagged as "Utterance layer" is what I called the layer **A**. As you can see in the figure, each utterance `u_i` in the figure is composed of words `w_j`, which are N-dimensional vectors. (You may omit the embedding layer for the purposes of this question) Assuming, for simplicity, that each `u_i` has equal number of Words, then each *group* of Bidirectional LSTM nodes in the Utterance Layer will have an input size of `(|U|, N)`. Yet, since there are `|C|` such utterances `u_i` in a Conversation, the dimensions of the entire input will be `(|C|, |U|, N)`.

[image: Bi-LSTM Model diagram]

Comment: @Maxim That doesn't necessarily apply to my question. If you read all of the admittedly lengthy description of the problem, the issue was never about batch size. A batch in my case would consist of multiple `Conversation`s. So, `(|C|, |U|, N)` is exactly a single input from a batch of _multiple_ such `Conversation`s. If we call batch size as `|B|`, then I would have to say `batch_input_shape=(|B|, |C|, |U|, N)`. It is another way to declare what I already _am_ declaring, but it is irrelevant to the core of my problem.

Comment: Do the input is intentionally `rank=4`? Plain Keras LSTM doesn't support it

Comment: This part of your question is "very" obscure: "*As the paper describes, I intend to group each utterance (i.e. each (|U|, N)) of that input and feed it to a Bi-LSTM layer with |U| units. This means that there should be |C| x |U| different Bi-LSTM units, grouped into |C| different partitions for each Utterance. The output of each of those C groups will then be fed into another Bi-LSTM layer, say B.*" -- What do you mean by "having `|U|` units? Do you mean steps in the output? And then `|C| x |U|` units? Your picture doesn't seem to show any of this.

Comment: @DanielMöller You are right, I guess. I edited that paragraph of my question to clarify it a bit. Also, I added some more explanation to the last paragraph. (i.e. the one where I describe the figure and how it corresponds to my question) Hope it helps clarify things a bit.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about how it works.... there is no need or implication to have "C x U" units in the model. Unless you have a clear reason for that, other than creating what is in the picture, it's not necessary at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll create a net for what I see in the picture. For now I'm ignoring the "units" part I mentioned in my comment to your question.

This model does exactly what is shown in the picture. All utterances are completely separate from start to end.

```
model = Sequential()

#You have an extra time dimension that should be kept as is
#So we add a TimeDistributed` wrapper to the first layers

model.add(TimeDistributed(Embedding(dictionaryLength,N), input_shape=(C,U)))

#This is the utterance layer. It works in "word steps", keeping "utterance steps" untouched    
model.add(TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(M//2, return_sequences=False))))

#Is the pooling really demanded by the article?
#Or was it an attempt to remove one of the time dimensions?
#Not adding it here because I used `return_sequences=False` 


model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(someSize//2,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(anotherSize)) #is this a CRF layer???

model.summary()
```

Notice that in every Bidirectional layer, I divided the output size by two, so it's important that `M` and `someSize` are even numbers.

Comment: From what I could understand about the use of `TimeDistributed` wrapper, it seems like it would apply the layer Embedding to `|C|` temporal slices of my input. Since each of those `|C|` slices would have the shape `(|U|, N)`, shouldn't the `input_shape` parameter be `(|C|, |U|, N)`?

Comment: With an Embedding layer, N only appears later. (See N as the output size of the embedding).

Comment: If you don't have an embedding layer, then you're right.

Comment: The considered input shape is always the "model's" input shape. The shape of your initial data, which is `(conversations, conversation_length, utterance_length)` if your're using an embedding layers, and `(conversations, conversation_length, utterance_length, N)` if you're not using embedding layers.